# Change colour and size of font in header of tabBox

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Although I am not very familiar with CSS, I have been able to include it in my R code to change various elements of my shiny app. However, I am unable to work out which element I need to change in order to change the colour and size of the font in the header of my tabBox, which comes from the package shinydashboard.

The other boxes in my app have headers with dark backgrounds and light fonts. I have been able to change the background of the tabBox header so it is dark (see below code), but there is no element I see that seems to affect the font.

I can change the font size of the tab labels using `font-size` in the `body`, or I can change the colour of the text in the box using `color`. But I am not able to find anything that relates to the attributes of the header title itself!

Thanks for your help.

Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tabBox(title = "Title of box", 
           tabPanel("Tab A"),
           tabPanel("Tab B")),
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                              /* tabBox background */                    
                              .nav-tabs-custom>.nav-tabs {
                              background-color: #2F4858;
                              }
                             '
    )
    )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to find things like this is to use the right-click menu item "Inspect element" (in Firefox, similar names in other browsers, but the built-in browser in RStudio isn't as good as the standalone ones).  Click where the title should be and it will be highlighted, with lots of CSS properties shown in a panel on the right of the screen.  Mine shows

[image: screenshot]

with the title highlighted in the main display.  Starting at the top, look for properties that interest you.  I see both `font-size` and `color` in the third group.  It has a slightly confusing top line:  the part saying `AdminLTE.min.css:7` says where this definition was found, the rest `.nav-tabs-custom > .nav-tabs > li.header` is the selector that is active for this element.

So to change the size and color, use that selector, e.g. put this in your `tabBox`:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
 /* tabBox background */                    
 .nav-tabs-custom>.nav-tabs {
     background-color: #2F4858;
 }
 .nav-tabs-custom > .nav-tabs > li.header {
     font-size: 40px;
     color: white; 
 }')
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using 'Inspect element' but nothing seemed to relate to the text. This sounds good - I'll check and get back to you :)